# mailto HTML e-mail link with dynamicly built subject

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

Hi need to build a subject dynamically. I.e. I have a input with some data which I want to add to subject.

For example if I just build html I can write the following:

```
<span style="color: #434343; font-family: 'Segoe UI REGULAR'; font-size: 12pt;">
   <text id="supportDescription">Id is '[context.eventId]' .</text>
 </span>
```

While opening html I'll see `Id is 345` (`345` is an argument)
Instead of adding an `id` to the html, I want to add a `mailto` link including the `id`:

```
<a href="mailto:name@gmail.com?subject=The%20 reply for evetId '[context.eventId]'">Send mail </a>
```

Will the substation work here also. And the subject will be `The reply for evetId 345`

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a jQuery event handler to put any text entered in the input into the link when the value of the input is changed. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1533tvfg/)**

```
$('input#eventid'). on('change', function() {
    var link = "mailto:name@gmail.com?subject=The%20reply%20for%20evetId%20" + $(this). val();
    $('a#mailto').attr('href', link);
});
```